# How to get the current file path and know if the file is saved

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, filesystems

I'm making a simple text editor in .net. I need to know how to get two things to work:

1. I need to know the full path of the current working file in the editor
2. I need to prompt the user to save the file on exit if it's not already saved (at all)

Please explain on how to get the above implemented. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: "the current working file" doesn't really say much about the how you opened your file. Please show some code to make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: @DavidPerlman by opening a file by choosing the application in "open with" ?

Comment: The full path of the file would be the filename of the file you loaded, most likely using a dialog box like system.windows.forms.openfiledialog, or, if you have not loaded a file (new file), then it would be the name of the file returned from a dialog box such as system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.

Comment: If you want to track whether the file is dirty or not, then add a Boolean flag to your program somewhere and anytime the users changes the textbox which represents your editor, or whatever control you are using, which will most likely have a TextChanged event, or something similar, then set the Boolean flag to True. 

Also, you will need to set, or clear, this flag anytime a file is loaded or saved. 

With this flag in place you can check it during the applications, or main forms, close event; if it is set to True, then prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: @RandyDodson Thanks for the reply. If the user opened the file by choosing the application in a "open with" dialog, how would I know the file path of the opened file?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class which will explain how you can select file from your file system. This is where you can start.

Saving the file is simple, you can check the file exists by using [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx); for example the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file) and [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo) classes to start with, then come back here for further questions, which will be inevitable.

Good luck.